# Node.js curl external site

Tags: node.js, request

I have a server in Express.js. I would like to do curl request to some sites, to e.g. calculate external links.
How can I do it?
Here is a part of the code:

```
    app.post("/check", function(req, res) {

    console.log(req)
    var link = req.body.url;
    console.log(link)
   // console.log(url);
    request(link, function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            res.json({ body: body });
        }
    });
});
```

But for some sites I get this error:

```
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
```

How can I resolve the problem?